# request for jquery related simple help

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to make some change in the following code which updates the number of votes by clicking on it with jquery. However, as shown in the image below, i want to display the vote number out of the box. I want to make it so that I click on the same green box, however I display the number out of the green box. I having difficulty making that. 
[image]

Here's the original code:
Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$(".vote").click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this);

if(name=='up'){
$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "up_vote.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,

   success: function(html)   {
    parent.html(html);
    }  }); 
}else{
$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "down_vote.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,

   success: function(html)   {
       parent.html(html);
  }   
 });
}
return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

and here's html part:

```
<div id="main">
<div class="box1">
<div class='up'><a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="up"><?php echo $up; ?></a></div>
</div>
<div class='box2' ><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
</div>
```

Here's Css:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
font-family:'Georgia', Times New Roman, Times, serif;
}
#main{
height:80px; border:1px dashed #29ABE2;margin-bottom:7px;
width:500px;
}

a{
color:#DF3D82;
text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover{
color:#DF3D82;
text-decoration:underline;
}

.up{
height:40px; font-size:24px; text-align:center; background-color:#009900; margin-bottom:2px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}
.up a{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;
}

.up a:hover{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;
}

.down{
height:40px; font-size:24px; text-align:center; background-color:#cc0000; margin-top:2px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}

.down a{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;
}

.down a:hover{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;
}

.box1{
float:left; height:80px; width:50px;
}

.box2{
float:left; width:440px; text-align:left;
margin-left:10px;height:60px;margin-top:10px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:18px;
}


</style>
```

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: Can you post the style definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CE4xh/) for you.

In short, number goes inside an element defined by `parent` variable. Replace `parent = $(this)` with `parent = $(this).parents('.box1')` and `parent.html(html)` inside ajax callback with `parent.append(html)`

**Update**

After a bit more fiddling: http://jsfiddle.net/CE4xh/1/.

I added `<div class="number"></div>` after `<div class="up">`, this is a placeholder for a number. 
There is a CSS class `.number` for it, making it red and centered. In this variant of the code you don't have to change ajax callbacks, you just need to set `parent = $(this).parents('.box1').find('.number')`

Comment: Thanks.. but it does not work when i try to combine this code with mine to get the dynamic number from database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it does not seem to work when I try to combime your code with mine to get the dynamic number from database. Please see this:
http://jsfiddle.net/EZtCr/

Here is simple up_vote.php code:
http://pastebin.com/M2dipj7Z

I'll highly appriciate any help. Thanks again.

Comment: I changed code, seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/nev3rm0re/EZtCr/5/. Changes: switched to `$.post()` instead of `$.ajax()`, passing data as a JSON instead of a string, url is set to jsfiddle's echo server (it returns back `html` parameter that you send to it)